# Laravel 5: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I try to access a page I get MethodNotAllowedHttpException. This used to work, but can't figure out what I did to break it.

routes.php

```
Route::post('api', ['middleware' => 'api', 'uses' => 'DeviceController@api']);
```

DeviceController.php

```
public function api()
{
    return view('api');
}
```

api.blade.php (I have altered api.blade.php to rule it out as the source of the problem.)

```
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

app/Http/kernal.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
];
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'devices',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'devices' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Device::class,
    ],
],
```

app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

I am using postman to simulate POST requests.

Comment: From where do you call the route? It looks like you are calling `post` route to get the `get` route resources. So, it is giving you issue.

Comment: @PaladiN I am using Postman (chrome pulgin) to access http://localhost/api with a POST request

Comment: So, have you done authentication when you are accessing your api route ? as it uses the `api` middleware. Also could you post your error screenshot too.

Comment: @PaladiN thanks for your help, but i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I am forcing a secure connection with the .htaccess file while trying to use http.